# T-SQL IF statement explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm really puzzled by this one!! I'm sure it's simple but really can't figure it out!!

```
DECLARE @jobid INT = 100
   IF (@JobID >= 0)
 BEGIN 
SELECT * into #tmp FROM Persons 
 end
    ELSE
 BEGIN
SELECT * into #tmp FROM Persons1 
 end
```

It gives an error that the `#tmp` table already exists! Why it would validate both statements !

Of course my original query is huge and doing more, but that's a sample to illustrate my error.

Can anybody explain it please?

The `#tmp` table is not there, even when you try to drop it or change the name, still the engine validates both statements!

I'm using 2008 R2.

Thanks
Jason

Comment: 'cause you haven't dropped `#tmp` from a previous run?

Comment: I am pretty sure you dont need a 'BEGIN' after the 'ELSE'.  Also, according to MSDN ELSE needs to come after END? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Comment: @p.campbell - Nope thats not it. If you tried the code you would notice that it is the parser that raises the error not the runtime. The error message is almost the same between them. The parser error will give you `Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1` and the runtime error will give you `Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6`.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson you're right, as always. /bows

Comment: @p.campbell not always I am a fast to delete when wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run it over Linked Server? **Or** you not deleted the one from previous run.

Try to create #tmp table prior to `IF` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(fields...)

DECLARE @jobid INT = 100
IF (@JobID >= 0)
BEGIN 
  INSERT #tmp
  SELECT * FROM Persons 
end
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT #Tmp
  SELECT * FROM Persons1 
end
```

**or** delete provious one

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
  EXEC('DROP TABLE #tmp')
GO

DECLARE @jobid INT = 100
   IF (@JobID >= 0)
 BEGIN 
SELECT * into #tmp FROM Persons 
 end
    ELSE
 BEGIN
SELECT * into #tmp FROM Persons1 
 end
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, no it's not linked server, just local, but the table doesn't exist, and i'm trying to understand why it throw that error, even with IF OBJECT_ID('#tmp') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #tmp
GO

Comment: You need to check `IF OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#tmp') IS NOT NULL` as @diaho wrote.

Comment: The parser does not like the same-named table created more than once within the batch (even though it will actually only be created once at execution time).  If the schemas are the same and you don't want to explicitly create the table (maybe there are a lot of columns), you could first select into #tmp where 1=2 to create the temp table, and then insert as above.

Answer (score 2):

`#tmp` may already be created in `tempDB` from previous runs of your query. If you are not using `#tmp` anywhere in your query prior to that block, you could do something like the following prior to that block of code to ensure it's always ready to go:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...But Believe it or not, it's not there....try any other name, still gives the same error !!

Comment: You're right @JYousef. A Google search of the error (Msg 2714, Level 16 ... There is already an object named '#tmp' in the database.) shows that there is a limitation of the temporary tables. Is the schema for `Persons` and `Persons1` the same? If so I would recommend the first solution that @Oleg recommended.

Comment: Thanks, Yep I'm using the first way like @Oleg recommended but I was puzzled why it would validate and give that error!! Thanks for all your help.